# apache drill "no current connection" error

Tags: apache-drill

I am using the most recent version of drill on windows machines in embedded mode. However, I always get "no current connection" errors when sending any queries. Also, the web server localhost:8047 does not work either. Here is what I see when I try to start drill.

[image]

I have tried both Java JDK 8 and 9, on two separate windows machines and got the same error. I searched about this matter but could not get any workarounds so far.

Any fix to this? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved by setting JAVA_HOME correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another clue that might help others!! I had the same problem "No current connection" on Windows 10 and went around in MANY circles trying to solve it by:

1. Making sure JAVA_HOME was set properly - ok
2. Checking in the cmd window to make sure I could cd %JAVA_HOME% - ok
3. Making sure I had added %JAVA_HOME%\bin to the PATH - ok
4. Checking in the cmd window to make sure I could cd %JAVA_HOME%\bin - ok
5. Trying to find conflicting JARs - there were none anywhere

Finally, I solved the problem: **USE JDK VERSION 7 or 8**

I blew away my version 9, reinstalled version 8, set JAVA_HOME again, and then started Drill with sqlline.bat -u "jdbc:drill:zk=local"

I tested it and got this!!!

```
0: jdbc:drill:zk=local> SELECT version FROM sys.version;
+----------+
| version  |
+----------+
| 1.12.0   |
+----------+
1 row selected (1.326 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Hadoop-3.1.2: Datanode and Nodemanager shuts down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54644231/hadoop-3-1-2-datanode-and-nodemanager-shuts-down)

Stuxen in the above thread provided the exact solution and it worked for me.