# Hadoop-3.1.2: Datanode and Nodemanager shuts down

Tags: hadoop, hadoop3

I am trying to install Hadoop(3.1.2) on Windows-10, but data node and node manager shuts down.

I have tried downloading and placing the winutils.exe and hadoop.dll files under bin directory. I have also tried changing the permissions of the files and running as an administrator. But it didn't fix the error

Datanode shutdown error

```
2019-02-12 12:01:30,856 INFO checker.ThrottledAsyncChecker: Scheduling a check for [DISK]file:/D:/Installs/IT/hadoop-3.1.2/data/datanode
2019-02-12 12:01:30,888 WARN checker.StorageLocationChecker: Exception checking StorageLocation [DISK]file:/D:/Installs/IT/hadoop-3.1.2/data/datanode
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.stat(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/io/nativeio/NativeIO$POSIX$Stat;
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.stat(Native Method)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.getStat(NativeIO.java:455)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.loadPermissionInfoByNativeIO(RawLocalFileSystem.java:796)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.loadPermissionInfo(RawLocalFileSystem.java:710)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.getPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:678)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.mkdirsWithExistsAndPermissionCheck(DiskChecker.java:233)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDirInternal(DiskChecker.java:141)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDir(DiskChecker.java:116)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.StorageLocation.check(StorageLocation.java:239)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.StorageLocation.check(StorageLocation.java:52)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.checker.ThrottledAsyncChecker$1.call(ThrottledAsyncChecker.java:142)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-02-12 12:01:30,888 ERROR datanode.DataNode: Exception in secureMain
org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Too many failed volumes - current valid volumes: 0, volumes configured: 1, volumes failed: 1, volume failures tolerated: 0
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.checker.StorageLocationChecker.check(StorageLocationChecker.java:231)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:2776)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:2691)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:2733)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:2877)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:2901)
2019-02-12 12:01:30,888 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1: org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Too many failed volumes - current valid volumes: 0, volumes configured: 1, volumes failed: 1, volume failures tolerated: 0
```

Nodemanager shutdown error

```
2019-02-12 12:01:28,091 WARN localizer.ResourceLocalizationService: Failed to rename the local file under /tmp/hadoop-Deepb/nm-local-dir/filecache
2019-02-12 12:01:28,185 ERROR nodemanager.NodeManager: Error starting NodeManager
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.stat(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/io/nativeio/NativeIO$POSIX$Stat;
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.stat(Native Method)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.getStat(NativeIO.java:455)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.loadPermissionInfoByNativeIO(RawLocalFileSystem.java:796)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.loadPermissionInfo(RawLocalFileSystem.java:710)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.getPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:678)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService.initializeLocalDir(ResourceLocalizationService.java:1435)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService.initializeLocalDirs(ResourceLocalizationService.java:1405)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService.serviceInit(ResourceLocalizationService.java:260)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:164)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:108)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl.serviceInit(ContainerManagerImpl.java:318)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:164)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:108)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceInit(NodeManager.java:477)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:164)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:933)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:1013)
2019-02-12 12:01:28,201 INFO service.AbstractService: Service org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService failed in state STOPPED
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.replaceNode(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1106)
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.remove(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1097)
        at java.util.Collections$SetFromMap.remove(Collections.java:5460)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DirectoryCollection.deregisterDirsChangeListener(DirectoryCollection.java:224)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LocalDirsHandlerService.deregisterLocalDirsChangeListener(LocalDirsHandlerService.java:258)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService.serviceStop(ResourceLocalizationService.java:429)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.stop(AbstractService.java:220)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stop(ServiceOperations.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:102)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.stop(CompositeService.java:158)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStop(CompositeService.java:132)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl.serviceStop(ContainerManagerImpl.java:703)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.stop(AbstractService.java:220)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stop(ServiceOperations.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:102)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.stop(CompositeService.java:158)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStop(CompositeService.java:132)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceStop(NodeManager.java:487)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.stop(AbstractService.java:220)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stop(ServiceOperations.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:102)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:67)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService$CompositeServiceShutdownHook.run(CompositeService.java:184)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-02-12 12:01:28,201 WARN service.CompositeService: When stopping the service org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.replaceNode(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1106)
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.remove(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1097)
        at java.util.Collections$SetFromMap.remove(Collections.java:5460)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DirectoryCollection.deregisterDirsChangeListener(DirectoryCollection.java:224)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LocalDirsHandlerService.deregisterLocalDirsChangeListener(LocalDirsHandlerService.java:258)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService.serviceStop(ResourceLocalizationService.java:429)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.stop(AbstractService.java:220)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stop(ServiceOperations.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:102)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.stop(CompositeService.java:158)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStop(CompositeService.java:132)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl.serviceStop(ContainerManagerImpl.java:703)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.stop(AbstractService.java:220)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stop(ServiceOperations.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:102)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.stop(CompositeService.java:158)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStop(CompositeService.java:132)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceStop(NodeManager.java:487)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.stop(AbstractService.java:220)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stop(ServiceOperations.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:102)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:67)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService$CompositeServiceShutdownHook.run(CompositeService.java:184)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-02-12 12:01:28,201 INFO service.AbstractService: Service org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl failed in state STOPPED
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.replaceNode(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1106)
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.remove(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1097)
        at java.util.Collections$SetFromMap.remove(Collections.java:5460)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DirectoryCollection.deregisterDirsChangeListener(DirectoryCollection.java:224)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LocalDirsHandlerService.deregisterLocalDirsChangeListener(LocalDirsHandlerService.java:258)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService.serviceStop(ResourceLocalizationService.java:429)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.stop(AbstractService.java:220)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stop(ServiceOperations.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:102)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.stop(CompositeService.java:158)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStop(CompositeService.java:132)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl.serviceStop(ContainerManagerImpl.java:703)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.stop(AbstractService.java:220)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stop(ServiceOperations.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:102)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.stop(CompositeService.java:158)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStop(CompositeService.java:132)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceStop(NodeManager.java:487)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.stop(AbstractService.java:220)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stop(ServiceOperations.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:102)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:67)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService$CompositeServiceShutdownHook.run(CompositeService.java:184)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-02-12 12:01:28,201 WARN service.CompositeService: When stopping the service org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.replaceNode(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1106)
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.remove(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1097)
        at java.util.Collections$SetFromMap.remove(Collections.java:5460)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DirectoryCollection.deregisterDirsChangeListener(DirectoryCollection.java:224)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LocalDirsHandlerService.deregisterLocalDirsChangeListener(LocalDirsHandlerService.java:258)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService.serviceStop(ResourceLocalizationService.java:429)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.stop(AbstractService.java:220)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stop(ServiceOperations.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:102)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.stop(CompositeService.java:158)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStop(CompositeService.java:132)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl.serviceStop(ContainerManagerImpl.java:703)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.stop(AbstractService.java:220)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stop(ServiceOperations.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:102)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.stop(CompositeService.java:158)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStop(CompositeService.java:132)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceStop(NodeManager.java:487)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.stop(AbstractService.java:220)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stop(ServiceOperations.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:102)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:67)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService$CompositeServiceShutdownHook.run(CompositeService.java:184)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-02-12 12:01:28,201 INFO service.AbstractService: Service NodeManager failed in state STOPPED
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.replaceNode(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1106)
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.remove(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1097)
        at java.util.Collections$SetFromMap.remove(Collections.java:5460)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DirectoryCollection.deregisterDirsChangeListener(DirectoryCollection.java:224)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LocalDirsHandlerService.deregisterLocalDirsChangeListener(LocalDirsHandlerService.java:258)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService.serviceStop(ResourceLocalizationService.java:429)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.stop(AbstractService.java:220)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stop(ServiceOperations.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:102)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.stop(CompositeService.java:158)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStop(CompositeService.java:132)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl.serviceStop(ContainerManagerImpl.java:703)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.stop(AbstractService.java:220)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stop(ServiceOperations.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:102)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.stop(CompositeService.java:158)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStop(CompositeService.java:132)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceStop(NodeManager.java:487)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.stop(AbstractService.java:220)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stop(ServiceOperations.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:102)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:67)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService$CompositeServiceShutdownHook.run(CompositeService.java:184)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-02-12 12:01:28,201 WARN service.AbstractService: When stopping the service NodeManager
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.replaceNode(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1106)
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.remove(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1097)
        at java.util.Collections$SetFromMap.remove(Collections.java:5460)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DirectoryCollection.deregisterDirsChangeListener(DirectoryCollection.java:224)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LocalDirsHandlerService.deregisterLocalDirsChangeListener(LocalDirsHandlerService.java:258)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService.serviceStop(ResourceLocalizationService.java:429)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.stop(AbstractService.java:220)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stop(ServiceOperations.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:102)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.stop(CompositeService.java:158)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStop(CompositeService.java:132)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl.serviceStop(ContainerManagerImpl.java:703)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.stop(AbstractService.java:220)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stop(ServiceOperations.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:102)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.stop(CompositeService.java:158)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStop(CompositeService.java:132)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceStop(NodeManager.java:487)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.stop(AbstractService.java:220)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stop(ServiceOperations.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:102)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:67)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService$CompositeServiceShutdownHook.run(CompositeService.java:184)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-02-12 12:01:28,201 INFO nodemanager.NodeManager: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
```

I know this is too much to ask because of the cumbersome task of hadoop installation but any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I overwrote all the files under **bin** directory with [these files](https://github.com/s911415/apache-hadoop-3.1.0-winutils/tree/master/bin) and everything started working as expected

Answer (score 2):

In `C:\BigData\hadoop-2.9.1\etc\hadoop` directry, open `hdfs-site.xml` file and set namenode and datanode location as

`/BigData/hadoop-2.9.1/data/namenode`

`/BigData/hadoop-2.9.1/data/datanode`

Then

1. Open **cmd** as **administrator.**
2. Type and run `stop-all.cmd`
3. `hadoop namenode –format`
4. `start-all.cmd`

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to run the start-*.cmd commands from a command-window opened as Administrator, and not as a user.  Of course, before that you have to set-up those 4 config-files and winutils.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem when starting Hadoop. Installing the missing dll file—in my instance, msvcr120.dll—fixed my problem. Try executing the winutils file in the bin folder and if you get an error claiming that your winutils file cannot be launched because a dll file is missing then download the missing dll file from google. Please refer to the following YouTube video for more precise instructions.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=knAS0w-jiUk&t=847s

I hope this corrects the issue.